# Is the following proof of the product rule correct?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

I recently came up with a proof of the product rule that I would like to share with you. It might not be correct, so I'd be happy to receive feedback.

---

Let $y=f(x)g(x)$. Take the natural logarithm of both sides:
$$
\log y = \log (f(x)g(x))=\log f(x)+\log g(x)
$$
Differentiate both sides:
$$
\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{f(x)}f'(x)+\frac{1}{g(x)}g'(x)
$$
Multiply both sides by $y=f(x)g(x)$:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=f(x)g(x)\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\right) \\
&=g(x)f'(x)+g'(x)f(x) \\
&=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)
\end{align}

Comment: It works only for positive functions and assumes that the derivative of $\log x $ is $\frac  1 x$. It is better to use the usual proof which relies only on the definiton of derivative.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for giving me feedback. What exactly do you mean by 'it assumes that the derivative of $\log x$ is $\frac{1}{x}$'? I thought that this was always true (at least, it is always true for positive real $x$). I am unfamiliar with complex-valued logarithms, if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: @Joe: I think Kavi just means that in the proof of a fairly badic result, you use what could be considered a much stronger result (in particular, have you proven the derivative of $\log x$ is $1/x$?

Comment: @Clayton Hmmm. If I define $\log x$ as $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}dt$, then it seems to follow from the fundamental theorem of calculus that $\frac{d}{dx}\log(x)=1/x$. But I understand if you think this is a little heavy-handed.

Comment: @Joe does my answer answer your question

Comment: @Vivaan: Yes, it does, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would happen if $g(x)f(x)$ is $0$ for some $x$ then $ln(x)$ is not defined .
What if $f(x)g(x)$ $< 0 $ for some $x$ ? Then also $ln(x)$ will be undefined .

Proof of the product rule :

$$\lim_{h\to 0}{ f(x+h)g(x+h)-g(x)f(x)\over h}$$= $$\ \lim_{h\to 0} {f(x+h)g(x+h) -f(x+h)g(x)-g(x)f(x)+f(x+h)g(x)\over h}$$

=$$\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h)  \times \lim_{h\to 0} { g(x+h) - g(x) \over h }+g(x)  \lim_{h\to 0} {f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}$$

(One can apply limit laws because all limits exist since both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable.)

Then by continuity of $f(x)$ the product rule follows .